# Query fails from application but runs fine in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, c#, type-conversion, nhibernate

I have a query that runs fine when executed from SSMS but when done so from the application, it fails with a (database level) exception.

```
select ksprintid
from kshistory_akt h
where cast(h.serialno as decimal(28)) >= 1
    and h.sku = '11105031'
```

The application error is

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   bei NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader.Read()
   bei NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
   bei NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
   bei NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
```

The code that executes it:

```
ISessionFactory _factory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(_factory.OpenSession());
IList printedJobs = _factory.GetCurrentSession()
    .CreateSQLQuery("select 1 from kshistory_akt h where cast(h.serialno as decimal(28)) >= :start and h.sku = :material")
    .SetString("material", "11105031")
    .SetParameter<int>("start", 1)
    .List();
```

But, the weird thing is that the result set of

```
select ksprintid
from kshistory_akt h
where h.sku = '11105031'
```

(without the actual cast) is **empty**:

[image: Empty result set]

So - how can an empty result cause an conversion error? And why doesn't it happen from within SSMS?

And to top it off: This only happens on **one** of three servers where this application runs. Every other server happily runs the command from the application without any errors (as it should be, because empty results should not cause problems when converting, *right*?)

**SSMS Connection options**

```
ANSI_WARNINGS
ANSI_PADDING
ANSI_NULLS
ARITHABORT
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL
```

**Client Connection options**

```
ANSI_WARNINGS
ANSI_PADDING
ANSI_NULLS
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL
```

Comment: Do the different servers have the same data & indexes? Or different? serialno may still be evaluated regardless of that sku value returning 0 rows.

Comment: Also, check your connection flags in the client and SSMS.

Comment: @GarethLyons Not the same data, the production server causes the problem, the rest don't. They are replicated occasionally from production, so their data is definitely "older". Indices should be the same across all of them, is there a way I can reliably "dump" the whole table config (with indices, config options, etc) to make sure?

Comment: Please show your c# code.

Comment: @DanielHutmacher I added the options (I think you meant these?) - The only difference seems to be `ARITHABORT` but I already tried switching that OFF in SSMS, to no avail.

Comment: @McNets Added to the question, although I doubt it should make a difference, considering the same code / query runs fine on other servers.

Comment: What are the datatypes of serialno & sku in the db? Try SELECT h.serialno, TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(28), h.serialno) FROM kshistory_akt h. Any NULL values in the second column that aren't NULL in the first should indicate where your problem values are.

Comment: Ok, but the error is clear, or it expects a varchar on material, or h.serialno has some record with a non numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause contains an explicit datatype conversion, which is terrible for performance, and can also cause this type of problem.

This query will probably show you what's wrong:

```
select serialno AS notVeryDecimalSerialNo
from kshistory_akt h
where try_cast(h.serialno as decimal(28)) IS NULL;
```

As for possible solutions, try changing the `CAST` to `TRY_CAST` - but note that this may lead to results that you don't expect, because `TRY_CAST` returns NULL instead of a conversion error.

If I were to guess, your problem is that there is a `serialno` which won't convert to decimal, but that value is not found if you filter on `material='11105031'`. So if SQL Server filters the material first, your query succeeds, otherwise the conversion fails. For more details, here's a [blog post](https://sqlsunday.com/2016/02/17/intermittent-conversion-issues/) I wrote on the subject.

The performance problem that I mentioned is caused by the `CAST` in the `WHERE` clause, which prevents SQL Server from using an index properly. The `TRY_CAST` won't solve this, it only takes away the actual conversion error. For more on this, check out ["sargable" expressions](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/01/19/sargable-expression-performance/).

Comment: I know that there are numbers in that column that cannot be converted, but none that also match `11105031` in the other column. I also noticed that when I turn around the filters, the query works. My problem is that I don't know why one server seems to filter `serialno` first (and runs in to the problem), but all others seem to filter `material` first

Comment: That is the point. It's nearly impossible to *tell* SQL Server specifically which column/expression to filter first. And every server could have a different cached query plan, which is probably what you're seeing. For this to work, you'll need to fix the query or this problem will just keep coming back.

Comment: Okay, I see. But why does turning the conditions around work? If the server doesn't care for the order I give the conditions to him, why does the behaviour change when I re-arrange them? I'm sorry if those are naive questions, I just want to learn how to avoid this in the future. For now, you gave me the tools to handle the problem at hand - but what's the gist I take away from this? Don't assume conditions will follow any order at all (which seems what you're saying)?

Comment: It's not about the order, it's about where the calculation happens (on which side of the equal sign, if you will). So this works: `WHERE a=CAST(123 AS varchar(10))`, this won't: `WHERE CAST(a AS int)=123`, because, potentially, not all values of `a` are valid int values, but 123 can always be converted to varchar.

Comment: Gotcha. The code actually does try to "catch" the problem beforehand by checking if the `sku` contains `serialno`s that can't be converted (via `is_numeric`) before running this query. So the assumption was apparently that when that "checking" returns that everything inside that `sku` can be converted, it can be reliably done. But the fact that the conversion might be run before the `sku` filter runs ... I guess no one thought of that... Thanks for your blog posts, too - good stuff!