# stored procedure runs fine in all sessions but one

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, configuration, dynamic-sql, dm-exec-sessions

There are procedures that run fine manually [but not in a job](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/276427/22336), or fails when run [from an application](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/170620/22336), or [not work in SSIS SQL task](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/311672/22336)

Mine works in all sessions but one.

this is the code I am running - it calls a stored procedure that gets the trigger definition(s) and save it in a temp table.

works fine and it is part of my automation work.

```
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Jagannatha_sp_getTriggerDef') IS NOT NULL 
            DROP TABLE #Jagannatha_sp_getTriggerDef 
            
            CREATE TABLE #Jagannatha_sp_getTriggerDef ( 
            DB sysname not null,
            parent_name nvarchar(600) not null,
            object_id int not null,
            trigger_name sysname not null,
            is_disabled bit,
            i int not null,
            [trigger_definition] NVARCHAR(MAX) not null,
            primary key clustered (DB,trigger_name,i))

            truncate table #Jagannatha_sp_getTriggerDef 

            
            exec sp_getTriggerDef @dbname      = 'APCore', 
                                  @TableName   = 'dbo.receivedLog',
                                  @Drop_ONly   = 0,
                                  @Radhe       = '#Jagannatha_sp_getTriggerDef'


    SELECT *
          FROM #Jagannatha_sp_getTriggerDef
          order by db,i
```

I run it on a table that has no triggers - just to make it as simple as possible

[image]

it comes out with the warning

```
IF 'my_server\_DEVELOPMENT' <> @@ServerName THROW 50001, 'Wrong Server!!!',1
```

all good.

but then on this particular session:

[image]

and there is nothing different in this session, that I could spot so far.

```
SELECT *
  FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
  where login_name = 'my_company\my_user'
    and  session_id = @@SPID
```

[image]

the second one  is where it fails.
all others it works fine.

what can I do to find out what is different?
or even better, change the procedure so that it would work despite the difference?

Comment: `Invalid column name 'DB'` have you tried to change the column name?

Comment: @marcello miorelli, can you provide the code for the stored proc `sp_getTriggerDef`

Comment: What happens in that same session if you just directly call `exec sp_getTriggerDef ...`?

Comment: You would get this if there is a table called `#Jagannatha_sp_getTriggerDef` that is created at an outer scope and does not have column `DB` and this is present when the statement is compiled

Comment: @MartinSmith I was just reading about this in [your answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86854/22336)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way out of this problem.
I could not find out nor took the time to understand why exactly only one session was having this issue.

This procedure of mine is packed with [dynamic sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/224118/22336), and it uses internally a temporary table called `#Radhe`.

I was creating the temp table `#Radhe` inside of the [dynamic sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/172067/22336).

I decided to do something different: instead of `#Radhe` I would have a [temp table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86854/22336) called `##Radhe` that is created **outside** of the [dynamic sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/172300/22336) but used inside it in the same way.

and that did the trick for me in this situation.

this is a partial view of the code that is inside the stored procedure:

```
        CREATE TABLE ##Radhe(
        DB sysname not null,
        parent_name nvarchar(600) not null,
        object_id int not null,
        trigger_name sysname not null,
        is_disabled bit default(0),
        is_drop bit default(0),
        i int not null identity(1,1),
        [trigger_definition] NVARCHAR(MAX) not null,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (DB,trigger_name ,i)
    );

    SET @sql1 = N'USE '+ QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'


SET NOCOUNT ON
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED


' +
CASE WHEN @RADHE IS NULL 
                    THEN N'INSERT INTO ##Radhe([DB],[parent_name],[object_id],[trigger_name],[is_disabled],[trigger_definition])
                                SELECT [DB]=''[__Radhe__]'',
                                       [parent_name]=''___Shyam'',
                                       [object_id]=16108,
                                       [trigger_name]=''___Today only happens today!'',
                                       [is_disabled]=0,
                                       [trigger_definition]=''IF ''' + ''''' + @Server + ''''' + ''' <> @@ServerName THROW 50001, ''''Wrong Server!!!'''',1 '''

                    ELSE N' IF NOT  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @Radhe + ' R WHERE R.[DB]=''[__Radhe__]'')' + @vCrlf +
                       + N'INSERT INTO ##Radhe([DB],[parent_name],[object_id],[trigger_name],[is_disabled],[trigger_definition])
```

this is another glimpse of the dynamic sql code:

```
                     INSERT INTO ##Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,is_drop,trigger_definition) values
                             (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,1, 
                             ''IF EXISTS (SELECT ''''Radhe'''' FROM sys.triggers t wHERE t.[name] = ''   
                                + '''''''' + @strigger_name + '''''''' 
                                + '' AND CASE WHEN t.parent_id = 0 THEN t.parent_id ELSE object_id(''  
                                + '''''''' + @parent_name   + '''''''' + '') END  = t.parent_id )
                             '')

                 INSERT INTO ##Radhe(DB,parent_name,object_id,trigger_name,is_disabled,is_drop,trigger_definition) values
                             (QUOTENAME(db_name()),@parent_name,@object_id,@trigger_name,@is_disabled,1,''EXEC(''''BEGIN DROP TRIGGER '' + @trigger_name + '' '' +  CASE WHEN   @parent_name != ''DATABASE'' THEN  '' ''   ELSE  '' ON DATABASE END '' END +  ''END'''') '')
```

execution of several dynamic sql blocks and writing the result to a table - if parameter was supplied, or just a select.

```
SELECT @SQL4 = CASE WHEN @RADHE IS NULL THEN N'' 
                    ELSE N' INSERT INTO ' 
                            + @Radhe 
                            + N'([DB],[parent_name],[object_id],[trigger_name],[is_disabled],[i],[trigger_definition])'
                END       + N'

                            SELECT [DB],
                                   [parent_name],
                                   [object_id],
                                   [trigger_name],
                                   [is_disabled],
                                   [i],
                                   [trigger_definition]
                            FROM ##Radhe R
                            WHERE 1=1
                              AND (@Drop_ONly = 0) OR (@Drop_ONly = 1 AND (R.is_drop=1 OR R.[DB]=''[__Radhe__]'')  )
                            ORDER BY DB,I

OPTION (RECOMPILE)

'
SET @SQL4 = CAST(@SQL1 + @SQL2 + @SQL3 + @SQL4 AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
SET @ParamDefinition = N'@Drop_ONly BIT, @Server sysname, @DBNAME sysname, @CHECK_IF_TRIGGER_EXISTS BIT, @TABLEIDOUT int OUTPUT';

        BEGIN TRY

            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL4, 
                               @ParamDefinition, 
                               @Server                  = @Server,
                               @DBNAME                  = @DBNAME, 
                               @Drop_ONly               = @Drop_ONly, 
                               @CHECK_IF_TRIGGER_EXISTS = @CHECK_IF_TRIGGER_EXISTS, 
                               @TABLEIDOUT              = @TABLEID OUTPUT

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
```

and this is an example of the result of the execution of this procedure - a script to drop all [triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/264620/22336) in a database(bear in mind there are two different types of [triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/250382/22336)):

```
IF 'MY_SERVER' <> @@ServerName THROW 50001, 'Wrong Server!!!',1 
GO
use [MY_DATABASE]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'Radhe' FROM sys.triggers t wHERE t.[name] = 'tr_MStran_altertable' AND CASE WHEN t.parent_id = 0 THEN t.parent_id ELSE object_id('DATABASE') END  = t.parent_id )           
EXEC('BEGIN DROP TRIGGER tr_MStran_altertable  ON DATABASE END END') 
GO
GO
use [MY_DATABASE]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'Radhe' FROM sys.triggers t wHERE t.[name] = 'tgr_cola_update_from_profile_change' AND CASE WHEN t.parent_id = 0 THEN t.parent_id ELSE object_id('[dbo].[repl_ApplicationProfile]') END  = t.parent_id )           
EXEC('BEGIN DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[tgr_cola_update_from_profile_change]  END') 
GO
```

**UPDATE**

Now I know what happened as I can reproduce the error.
I can also avoid it.
I have also changed my shared temp table `##Radhe` to a temp table created inside the dynamic sql, exactly where I needed it. It is called `#Jagannatha_Baladeva`.

My stored procedure called `sp_getTriggerDef`accepts a parameter that is a temp table name, that I use to return the scripts generated.

When I create this temp table and name is with the same name of a temp table inside my procedure, there are problems.

So because there is a table called `#Jagannatha_Baladeva` INSIDE my stored procedure if outside I create a table with the same name, I might face strange situations.

to make it clear, in the outside table I name the first column `DB5 sysname not null,` but in the table INSIDE my procedure the same column is called `DB sysname not null,` so when I run the following code:

```
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Jagannatha_Baladeva') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Jagannatha_Baladeva 
        
        CREATE TABLE #Jagannatha_Baladeva ( 
        DB5 sysname not null,
        parent_name nvarchar(600) not null,
        object_id int not null,
        trigger_name sysname not null,
        is_disabled bit,
        i int not null,
        [trigger_definition] NVARCHAR(MAX) not null,
        primary key clustered (DB5,trigger_name,i))

        truncate table #Jagannatha_Baladeva 

        
        exec sp_getTriggerDef @dbname      = 'ORCA_Repl_Sub', 
                              @TableName   = null,--'dbo.receivedLog',
                              @Drop_ONly   = 1,
                              @Radhe       = '#Jagannatha_Baladeva'


SELECT *
      FROM #Jagannatha_Baladeva
      order by db,i
```

I get my original error:
[image]

I changed my column name to `DB` and my temp table name to `#some_other_table_name` but I still had the same error UNTIL I opened another session in my [SSMS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/184909/22336) and run the code again:

```
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#some_other_table_name') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #some_other_table_name
        
        CREATE TABLE #some_other_table_name ( 
        DB sysname not null,
        parent_name nvarchar(600) not null,
        object_id int not null,
        trigger_name sysname not null,
        is_disabled bit,
        i int not null,
        [trigger_definition] NVARCHAR(MAX) not null,
        primary key clustered (DB,trigger_name,i))

        truncate table #some_other_table_name

        
        exec sp_getTriggerDef @dbname      = 'ORCA_Repl_Sub', 
                              @TableName   = null,--'dbo.receivedLog',
                              @Drop_ONly   = 1,
                              @Radhe       = '#some_other_table_name'


SELECT *
      FROM #some_other_table_name
      order by db,i
```

and then it worked fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had more rep so I could just leave a comment on [Marcello's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/312669/22336)...

But I would recommend against the global temp table as they're often a security risk since any session can access it's contents.

Just make it an actual table that you manage yourself...